# Params keyword in JSON object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am creating a JSON object in code. But the JSON contains property `params`, so when I try to create object like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject json = JObject.FromObject(new
{
   jsonrpc = "2.0",
   method = "user.login",
   params = new
   {
      user = "user",
      password = "password"
   },
   id = 1
});
```

I get an error because VS thinks its `params` the keyword. Is there way how to create object like this or somehow use `params` without using `params`?

Comment: `params` is reserve keyword you can not able to use it

Comment: use `parameters` instead of `params`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use @params so you can escape special keywords

Comment: That was fast. Thanks.